# HTML/CSS Tag Bar Collapse for different screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries, navbar

I'm designing a webpage, and extracted this portion into a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h703xqbt/16/

I'm not being able to avoid several layers of tags instead of a single line when the screen resizes to a smaller value or when using a movile device.

I'm trying to make it collapse into a single button that shows a dropdown list with all the tags that don't fit the screen.

I'm familiar with media queries such as

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #button1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

but i'm not sure how to use it for this purpose.

I've seen some webpages that do this but it becomes very difficult to follow them as they have an enormous amount of details, and can't find the fundamentals.

Is this possible using only css? (i'm trying to avoid js and jquery as much as possible, for my own reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the tabs a width of 100% when the screen size is a certain width :)

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .tab-link {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

This way, the tabs will stay next to each other on wide screens, and occupy the full width on mobile devices, stacking on top of each other.

You can always change the `600px` media query to a smaller / larger width, and give the tabs themselves a width of something like `50%` if you would like two tabs next to each other.

I've created a new fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/5L6ft3qe/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, but it's not exactly what i'm trying to do. The idea of the dropdown list is to be hidden in a single button, so you can still si the contents of the current tag, and when you need to change the tab, click on the button, dropdown list appears, and you select it from there

Comment: So the 'contents' of the open tab are displayed directly underneath their parent tab, **before** the next closed tab? Unfortunately, that would be quite difficult to do with your current structure; you'd be far better off restructuring to have the contents contained within their respective parents in the HTML itself. Having said that, it sounds like you're trying to build a standard Twitter Bootstrap dropdown, and you may find it helpful to use that: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/. Try viewing that in mobile and expanding 'Dropdown' :)